# Squealing noise heard when A/C is turned on

Tags: noise, belt, motorhome

1990 g30 chassis Winnebago - When I turn on the AC, I get a loud squeal noise.  When I turn my steer wheel it gets worse. I changed my AC compressor but the noise is still there.  I sometimes get a chirping noise when the AC is off as well.
Power steering fluid is good.
Engine 454- 1990 Winnebago

Comment: what else is driven by the same belt as the AC compressor?  Is the power steering on the same belt?  Have you checked that the belt is not slipping?

Comment: @HandyHowie - I think you need to write that last bit as an answer. It is one of two things, both having to do with the power steering. I'm betting either the belt is loose, or the power steering pump is going out.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that the power steering and AC are driven by the same belt.  It may simply be that the belt is not tight enough and is slipping when extra load is added by turning on the AC or using the power steering.

It is also possible that the bearings on the power steering pump are worn, or even one of the other ancillaries driven by the same belt.

First thing to do is check the belt tension and while you are at it check the belt for wear.  If the noise doesn’t go away, you need to identify the exact location the noise is coming from and report back.  Make sure you keep your fingers and clothing away from operational belts.